# NAudio WaveMixerStream32 mixing multiple .wav files

Tags: naudio

I tried to mix two .wav files into one but can`t figure out why mixed .wav file time is twice greater of any of mixed .wav files. Can somebody explain please, what i am doing wrong?

```
WaveMixerStream32 mixer = new WaveMixerStream32();
WaveFileReader[] reader = new WaveFileReader[micDevices.Count];
WaveChannel32[] stream = new WaveChannel32[micDevices.Count];
mixer.AutoStop = true;
bool doMixing = false;
for (int i = 0; i < micDevices.Count; i++)
{
   bool mixChannel = micDevices[i].enabled == true;
   micDevices[i].stopRecording();
   if (mixChannel == false)
        continue;
   reader[i] = new WaveFileReader(micDevices[i].tmpWavFileName);
   stream[i] = new WaveChannel32(reader[i]);
   mixer.AddInputStream(stream[i]);
   doMixing = true;
}
if (doMixing)
{
   mixer.Position = 0;
   Wave32To16Stream wavmixer = new Wave32To16Stream(mixer);
   WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(tmpwavFileName, wavmixer);
   wavmixer.Dispose();
   mixer.Dispose();
}
```

all .wav files have same bitrate, channels count.

Comment: what do you hear when you play the mixed file?

Comment: after inspecting temp files and their format i found that problem was in .wav to .mp3 encoder. lamedll was called with wrong channels count. Thank you.

Comment: @gr8b: why would mp3 have anything to do with this? It looks like the code only deals with wav files.